# Bind drop down with data in new row of grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, grid

Im trying to add a new row in grid with dropdown as one column in it. Now im trying to bind data to the drop down when the new row is added but the data doesnt show up. Can anyone tell me whats the problem with my code?

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdJournal" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="lblDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAccounts" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="lblDescription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Debit">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="lblDebit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Credit">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="lblCredit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

and my codebehind is this

```
 private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("colDate", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("colAccount", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("colDescription", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("colDebit", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("colCredit", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["colDate"] = string.Empty;
        dr["colAccount"] = string.Empty;
        dr["colDescription"] = string.Empty;
        dr["colDebit"] = string.Empty;
        dr["colCredit"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        grdJournal.DataSource = dt;
        grdJournal.DataBind();
    }

    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox lblDate = (TextBox)grdJournal.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("lblDate");
                    DropDownList lblAccount = (DropDownList)grdJournal.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlAccounts");
                    TextBox lblDescription = (TextBox)grdJournal.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("lblDescription");
                    TextBox lblDebit = (TextBox)grdJournal.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("lblDebit");
                    TextBox lblCredit = (TextBox)grdJournal.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("lblCredit");
                    Classes.CRUD obj = new Classes.CRUD();
                    lblAccount.DataSource = obj.ShowAllAccounts();
                    lblAccount.DataTextField = "Key";
                    lblAccount.DataValueField = "Value";
                    lblAccount.DataBind();
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                    //Setting Values to new Row


                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["colDate"] = lblDate.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["colAccount"] = lblAccount.SelectedItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["colDescription"] = lblDescription.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["colDebit"] = lblDebit.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["colCredit"] = lblCredit.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);

                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                grdJournal.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                grdJournal.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();


    }
    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox lblDate = (TextBox)grdJournal.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("lblDate");
                    DropDownList lblAccount = (DropDownList)grdJournal.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlAccounts");
                    TextBox lblDescription = (TextBox)grdJournal.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("lblDescription");
                    TextBox lblDebit = (TextBox)grdJournal.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("lblDebit");
                    TextBox lblCredit = (TextBox)grdJournal.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("lblCredit");

                    lblDate.Text = dt.Rows[i]["colDate"].ToString();
               //     lblAccount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["colAccount"].ToString();
                    lblDescription.Text = dt.Rows[i]["colDescription"].ToString();
                    lblDebit.Text = dt.Rows[i]["colDebit"].ToString();
                    lblCredit.Text = dt.Rows[i]["colCredit"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Classes.CRUD obj = new Classes.CRUD();
        #region Binding Events

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetInitialRow();

            ddlType.DataTextField = "Value";
            ddlType.DataValueField = "Key";
            ddlType.DataSource = obj.ShowTypesOfTransactions();
            ddlType.DataBind();
        }

        #endregion


    }
```

Comment: Does `obj.ShowAllAccounts()` return any value?

Comment: yes it does. It return the result i want to bind to the drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

```
  private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox TextBoxName = (TextBox)grvStudentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtName");
                    TextBox TextBoxAge = (TextBox)grvStudentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtAge");
                    TextBox TextBoxAddress =
                      (TextBox)grvStudentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtAddress");
                    RadioButtonList RBLGender =
                      (RadioButtonList)grvStudentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("RBLGender");
                    DropDownList DrpQualification =
                      (DropDownList)grvStudentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("drpQualification");

                    //Added these lines

                    Classes.CRUD obj = new Classes.CRUD();
                    DrpQualification.DataSource = obj.ShowAllAccounts();
                    DrpQualification.DataBind();

                    //****************
                    TextBoxName.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col1"].ToString();
                    TextBoxAge.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col2"].ToString();
                    TextBoxAddress.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col3"].ToString();
                    RBLGender.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["Col4"].ToString();
                    DrpQualification.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["Col5"].ToString();
                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```